# Print composer custom table with sums for groups

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts, table

How do I build a result table within the print composer that aggreates the sums from an abundance field (integer) for the responding values?

| Species | Abundance |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1 |
| y | 1 |
| x | 1 |

Result

| Species | count |
| --- | --- |
| x | 2 |
| y | 1 |

I've tried several ways to aggregate and group_by but without success.